# Not authorized to list projects with keystone v3?

Tags: openstack, keystone

I set up keystone v3, and then created a domain `dom1`, a user `adm1` and grant this user to admin role. Authenticate this user with domain scope. Then create a project under `dom1`. I tried to list projects with the same token that created the project. All I got is `"You are not authorized to perform the requested action: identity:list_projects"`.

If I take out the rule `domain_id:%(domain_id)s` in policy.v3cloudsample.json for `"identity:list_projects"`, everything works well.

Why cannot I list projects with the rule `domain_id:%(domain_id)s`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to OpenStack API document, the API URL of listing projects must be filtered with domain ID. So in policy,json, `domain_id:%(domain_id)s` of `identity:list_projects` means the domain ID in URL filter must be equal to the domain ID that the token is scoped.

Comment: Hi @talihsu, Were you able to make it work without _(You are not authorized to perform the requested action: identity:list_projects)_

Comment: Hi Bik, without what? Thanks